# data.dat python

Tags: python

say i have the following data in a .dat file:

*A-1-2-3-4*B-8-2-4*C-4-2-5-1-5

how can i print the these data like this?:

A : 1 2 3 4

B : 8 2 4

C : 4 2 5 1 5

randomly print any one number for each letter.
A, B and C can be any word.
and the amount of the numbers can be different.
i know that it has some thing to do with the * and the -

Comment: what if I want to randomly print only one of the numbers?

Comment: `import random`, then `help(random)`.  It's easy, but we've already done enough of your homework :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read in the file, then `split()` the characters:

```
contents = open("file.dat").read()
for line in contents.split("*"):
  if not line: continue  # Remove initial empty string.
  line = line.strip()   # Remove whitespace from beginning/end of lines.
  items = line.split("-")
  print items[0], ":", " ".join(items[1:])
```

Comment: @Stephen, `items[1:].join(" ")` is a bug -- you need `' '.join(items[1:])` instead (I guess upvoters don't care about such miniscule details as to whether the code they're upvoting _works_;-).

Comment: what if to get the letters printed separate individually?

Comment: like ,print letter_a, print letter_b , print letter_c

Comment: @Alex : Thanks, fixed.  About the upvotes, i think it's because not all of us have interpreters in our heads. :)

Comment: @babikar : i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: what am i have to do if i want to like print A somewhere and B some where else same with C not after in each other

Comment: and how can i put the numbers in a list?

Comment: @babikar : about printing, that's gonna depend on hoe you want it printed.  to create a list of numbers: `num_list = items[1:]`

Comment: i want to put them in to a list so that i can print them separately

Comment: @babikar : Create a list before the for loop: `letters = []`, then append each letter within the loop: `letters.append(item[0])`.

Comment: say i have an output of this, i think its a list
['', 'AB-a-b-c-d', 'BC-f-c-a-r', 'CD-i-s-r']
i want to make the following:
['',[AB,a,b,c,d],[BC,f,c,a,r],[CD,i,s,r]]

Comment: @babikar - you need to split the original list elements on '-'.  `'AB-a-b-c-d'.split('-')` -> `[AB,a,b,c,d]`

Answer (score 1):

Also another option

```
line = "*A-1-2-3-4*B-8-2-4*C-4-2-5-1-5"
s = filter(bool, line.split("*"))
for i in s:
    i = i.split("-")
    print i[0], ":", i[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()`

```
data_string = '*A-1-2-3-4*B-8-2-4*C-4-2-5-1-5' #read in the data

data = data_string.split('*') #split the data at the '*'

for entry in data:
    items = entry.split('-')  #split data entries at the '-'
    letter = items[0]         #you know that the first item is a letter
    if not items[0]: continue #exclude the empty string
    print letter, ':',
    for num in items[1:]:
        print int(num),
    print '\n',
```